# TypeScript Use External Type in Declaration

Tags: typescript

How would it be possible to reference a type of a third party in a declaration file? The goal of this declaration is to generate types (index.d.ts) that would be referenced in JavaScript files for better typing support via `types` pointed to the generated `index.d.ts` in the project's `package.json`. The goal being usage/reference in JavaScript files/functions such as (this works without any references to third party types):

```
/**
 * @param {Models.Foo} foo
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getBaz(foo) {
  console.log(foo.baz);
  returns 'Hello World!';
}
```

Given the following declaration that uses express type `Handler` to a property of an exported `interface` of a declared `namespace`:

```
import * as express from 'express';

declare namespace Foo {
  export interface Bar {
    baz: express.Handler;
  }
}
```

With a `tsconfig.json` for primarily generate an `index.d.ts`:

```
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outDir": "types"
  }
}
```

Generates an `index.d.ts` of an empty exported object:

```
export {};
```

Is it possible to reference a type from third party definitions/types to generate a declaration file? If you need to specify that your declaration uses types/interfaces/classes from outside your project, how would that be accomplished? If I remove the reference to `express` the declaration generates perfectly fine.

Even just adding the `import` of express such as the following causes the same output empty object export (without anything inside the namespace referencing the types of the import):

```
import * as express from 'express';

// No actual reference to any express types
declare namespace Foo {
  export interface Bar {
    baz: string;
  }
}
```

In this situation `@types/express` are installed as a dev dependency. I can explore the contents of the express types without issue.

Maybe someone can point me to a declaration that references third party types?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a TS bug to me 

Comment: To be clear, this is in a JS project. The goal is to generate an `index.d.ts` that would be consumed in JSDoc comments. Technically if `export` is added in front of `declare namespace` it generates more than an empty object, but cannot be referenced in the JavaScript files with `types` specified in `package.json`. Without any reference to any external types, it works perfectly. Even just adding the `import ` causing it to output to export of an empty object.